# Can not find @Getter and @Setter

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, getter-setter, lombok

I've tried to add the users and authentication with OAuth. I followed by tutorial: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOgCMtYMr2Q&list=PLcoE64orFoVsxAam_BuQBrNC8IO238SwH&index=2)
Here is his source code: https://github.com/arocketman/Spring-oauth2-jpa-example

I've done exactly like him but my Intellij showed me some issuses.

I had to change my pom.xml from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Just to fix "Can not resolve `oauth2 symbol` in my configuration files.

But now the problem is that every `getSomething` or `setSomething` is marked red.

```
Error:(12, 12) java: class com.github.Spring.Blog.config.ResourceServerConfig is already defined in package com.github.Spring.Blog.config
Error:(3, 48) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations does not exist
Error:(4, 48) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations does not exist
Error:(18, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Getter
Error:(19, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Setter
Error:(3, 48) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations does not exist
Error:(4, 48) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations does not exist
Error:(14, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Getter
Error:(15, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Setter
...
```

Here is my source code: https://github.com/Incybro/Spring-Blog

After installing lombok and changing imports to `import lombok.*;`

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\config\ResourceServerConfig.java
Error:(12, 12) java: class com.github.Spring.Blog.config.ResourceServerConfig is already defined in package com.github.Spring.Blog.config
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\services\UserService.java
Error:(20, 53) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPassword()
  location: variable user of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\SpringBlogApplication.java
Error:(27, 55) java: constructor Role in class com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.Role cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(27, 73) java: constructor Role in class com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.Role cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Spring-Blog\src\main\java\com\github\Spring\Blog\services\CustomUserDetailsService.java
Error:(29, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getUsername()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(30, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getPassword()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(31, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(32, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(33, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(34, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isActive()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
Error:(36, 34) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getRoles()
  location: variable u of type com.github.Spring.Blog.entities.User
```

Comment: You have to add the Lombok Plugin to IntelliJ and enable annotation processing in the settings. Maybe you have to add the lombok as dependency in your pom file as well.

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Comment: It helped but it still dosen't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you need to add lombok plugin in your IDE.
to add plugin

- Go to File > Settings > Plugins
- Click on Browse repositories...
- Search for Lombok Plugin
- Click on Install plugin
- Restart IntelliJ IDEA

[see here for details](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

[for more details](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)

Comment: do you Restart IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Yes, I clicked "restart IDEA". There is no getter and setter marked red but still shows errors.

Comment: Do you want to see on TeamViewer?