# package lombok does not exist Gradle intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I tried all the mentioned solutions here
[lombok doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404454/package-lombok-does-not-exist)
but i couldn't be able to resolve this issue.

I used these dependencies..

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
```

here is the description of tech stack used :

```
gradle version: 7.4.2
jdk: 1.8
intellij idea: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
```

Can anyone guide me how to handle this issue?

Comment: Update your IDE to the latest version. A lot of Lombok fixes were done since 2019

Comment: sure let me try this one too

Answer (score 0):

perhaps adding these dependencies will help:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
```

final result looks like this:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
```

Comment: Took me two reads to realize that OP already does.

Comment: this is not working fine. i have added these 4 dependencies but it is not working fine.